# Filtering rows in Pandas, conditions False, but row is sill included

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I've got a Pandas dataframe (v0.25.3, Python 3.6) and I'm trying to do operations on rows that match certain conditions.  I've done this hundreds of times, but now I'm getting weird behavior that I can't figure out.  Specifically, I've got two conditions, and I want to capture only rows where both conditions are True, but I'm getting rows in my results where either or both conditions are False.

For example,

```
print(data.loc[1,"var1"] != None)
print(data.loc[1,"var2"] != None)
```

returns `False` and `True`, but when I run

```
thisData1 = data.loc[((data["var1"] != None) & (data["var2"] != None))]
print(thisData1.head())
```

row 1 is still in there...all the data is still in there!  If I use the older styling without `.loc` I get the same results.  Row 0 is sill in there and they are both `None`.  Furthermore, when I run just

```
print(len(data[data['var1'] != None]))
```

It again doesn't filter anything even though `print(data.loc[1,"var1"] != None)` => `False`

Everything here SEEMS to conform to the correct Pandas way to do this (e.g., see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)), and it usually works, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong in this case.  Can anybody spot my error or recommend a way a different/safer way to run these filters?  If the problem is my dataset, what should I check?

Comment: please add some sample data to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `notnull` instead of `!= None`

```
thisData1 = data[data["var1"].notnull() & data["var2"].notnull()]
```

Comment: Thank you. I got a work-around using `isinstance(x, str)` to work for my immediate issue, so I figured the problem was something about the `None`, but I didn't know the correct method in general...now I do.